# Angular filesaver download csv data with # is unable to download

Tags: special-characters, export-to-csv, fileserver

I'm new to coding. I'm doing a task to download a csv file from DB.

When I use angular filesaver to download the csv, if the content with #, the word after # will not be displayed. It would be appreciated if anyone can give me some hits to fix this :)

onBtnExportClick(){

```
      let testContent = "SOVEREIGN SURGICAL BLADES STERILE #11"

      saveAs('data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + testContent , 'TestFile.csv');
```

}

Answer (score 1):

fixed with this code

var blob = new Blob([r.FileContent], {type: r.FileMIMEType});
saveAs(blob, r.FileName);